# Linux: Make "ulimit" limits be cumulative across spawned "subprocesses"

Tags: linux, performance, security, ulimit

Let's say I have program #1 launching program #2 which is launching program #3.

If I call

```
ulimit -t 10
```

before calling program #1, then EACH program will be alloted 10 seconds of CPU time.

Could I have this limit apply to the total CPU time used by all 3 programs? Basically I'm talking about the time as shown by 'top -S' - this will show the total cumulative CPU time including all spawned "subprocesses".

Most useful to me would be to have this cumulative behavior apply for "-t" (CPU time). It would be great though if I could have it apply to the other flags as well (maximum memory used etc.).

If ulimit can't do this, is there an alternate way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at cgroups ("contol groups"):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups
- http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/

Answer (score 2):

this limit is *imposed per process* ; as long they are seen as different processes (top, htop, ps) the limit will be for each. rewrite the code and make the second and third program worker threads.